# Post formatting bug in WordPress

Tags: posts, formatting

I have a [Math counterexamples](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/) blog. [One post](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/existence-continuous-function-with-divergent-fourier-series/) contains the string

```
<strong>We now prove that</strong>
\begin{align*}
```

However, when that post is displayed without the "Continue reading" expanded, the closing bold string `</strong>` is removed creating a site rendering bug as you can see [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/) ==> In particular the Tag Cloud is in bold and it shouldn't.

The html source code in the wrong pages is:

```
<strong>We now prove that<br />
```

I tried to locate where the bad parsing of the post content could happen and looked at **formatting.php** putting some traces. But in the functions of **formatting.php**, the format is already wrong. So the error should take place before those functions are called.

I have to admit that I'm a beginner in WordPress and PHP...

**Do you have a clue of where I should have a look?**

Comment: can you you show us a page where the bug appears ?

Comment: Yes, in fact if you load the site from the root [http://www.mathcounterexamples.net](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net), you will see that the bug is present. And this is due to the post [EXISTENCE OF A CONTINUOUS FUNCTION WITH DIVERGENT FOURIER SERIES](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/existence-continuous-function-with-divergent-fourier-series/) which is the one I mention in my question. The post is in the main page downwards. The html </strong> is missing after the sentence "We now prove that". Thanks!